# how to get URL for iOS App store review page

Tags: ios, app-store

I need to create URL link to app review page for both app store and Google Play store. I have managed to do for Google Play but not getting around for app store. The link to app store is https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/emmas-diary/id594428605

### Google Play URL (this is working)

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pgs.emmasdiary&hl=en_GB&showAllReviews=true
```

### App Store for iOS

????

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS 10.3 reviewing app is changed slightly, the code spinet below will clear everything

```
func rateApp() {
    if #available(iOS 10.3, *) {
        SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()   // managed automatically by SKStoreReviewController
    } else if let url = URL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/" + "yourAppID") {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [ : ], completionHandler: nil)  // managed manually through concatenating the URL
    }
}
```

For ref. check below image (image source: Google images.)

[image]

Hope answered you